# How to go back to previous opened file in Vim?

Tags: vim

I can use `gf` to go to the file with name under/after cursor, is there any command to go back to the original file without relaunch vim to open it?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Try using this shortcut:

```
CTRL-^
```

Vim documentation `:help CTRL-^`:

> ```
> CTRL-^    Edit the alternate file.  Mostly the alternate file is
>           the previously edited file.  This is a quick way to
>           toggle between two files.  It is equivalent to ":e #",
>           except that it also works when there is no file name.
> ```

And `:help alternate-file`

> If there already was a current file name, then that one becomes the alternate
>   file name.  It can be used with "#" on the command line |:_#| and you can use
>   the |CTRL-^| command to toggle between the current and the alternate file.
>   However, the alternate file name is not changed when |:keepalt| is used.
>   An alternate file name is remembered for each window.

Comment: Just for clarification, both `CTRL-^` (i.e. `CTRL-SHIFT-6`) and `CTRL-6` work for me.

Comment: For quick access:
    nmap <leader>bb <c-^><cr>

Comment: Doesn't work on mac

Comment: `CTRL-SHIFT-6` works for me on macos 12.5.1

Answer (score 169):

Try following command

```
:e#
```

It will take you to the previously opened file stored in a buffer.

---

If you have gone deep down the hierarchy of files by typing multiple `gf`, vim stores all the files in numbered buffers

Then following command will take you to the `n`th file in a buffer. *(n = 1,2,3,..)*

```
:e#n
```

Comment: Is there a way to store files in a register like with recording or yanking?

Comment: ctrl-^ is a little awkward on the fingers imo, this may be slightly slower but not as frustrating.

Comment: @DanielThompson what you're looking for is buffers https://medium.com/@Sohjiro/introduction-to-vim-buffers-dd966ff518d

Comment: @IsaacPak ctrl + 6 will also work, the way to press it is ctrl (left pinky) + ^ (right index) in qwerty keyboards.

Comment: using neovim here, with control mapped to caps lock, and pressing control+shift+6 is some serious finger gymnastics ‍♂️

Comment: Is there documentation about `#` and the rest of the "special file aliases"?